# Projecting from Lambert azimuthal equal area (LAEA) projection to WGS84 without distortion using OGR

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, wgs84

I need to convert a shapefile from Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection system (North Pole) to WGS84. When I use QGIS to do this, the lines that cross the anti-meridian cross over (horizontal black lines in the image).
To avoid this, I found one solution that worked, which is clipping the region of interest and making sure the region I clipped does not include the -180 and 180 longitudes (the reason for distortion apparently), but is there an out-of-the-box tool in GDAL/OGR or to deal with this problem without doing manual clipping or having to program it myself?

Source projection (Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection):
[image: Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection (North Pole)]

Target projection (WGS84) that looks distorted:
[image: Distorted map in WGS84].

Solution that worked for the region of interest:

[image: projected region after clipping]

The '-wrapdateline' option in ogr results in a similar but slightly different distorted output.

[image: ogr -warpdateline output]

Answer (score 2):

I've used the before for lines, not sure how it will work on Polygons:

```
ogr2ogr -wrapdateline output_file.shp input_file.shp
```

https://gisforthought.com/clipping-datasets-to-the-dateline-in-ogr2ogr/