# Transformation from Lambert azimuthal equal-area to WGS84 uncovers polar region

Tags: coordinate-system, r, spherical-geometry

I'm having an issue where a transformation from a projected coordinate system (Lambert azimuthal equal-area) to WGS84 changes the shape of my polygon near the polar region. The real data creates a large sf polygon that extends from near the equator over the southern pole.

If I first project the lat-long points into a custom LAEA (roughly) centered over their spherical centroid before turning them into a polygon via...

```r
polygon <- points %>% st_transform(crs = "+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=25.8 +lat_0=-26.0") summarize(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% st_cast('POLYGON')
```

[image: Lambert azimuthal equal area polygon that covers the southern pole.]

But when I leave the points unprojected in WGS84 / lat-long ...

```r
polygon <- points %>% summarize(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% st_cast('POLYGON')
```

The resulting polygon no longer covers the southern pole, extending only to about 82 degrees south. That corresponds to the southern coast, but not to where points internal to the polygon, e.g. st_sample(), are translated to.

[image: WGS84 polygon that only extends to ~82 degrees south latitude.]

The closest post here that I was able to find was [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353249/projecting-from-lambert-azimuthal-equal-area-laea-projection-to-wgs84-without), but it didn't have much of an answer and didn't use R or sf.

**Reproducible Example**

```r
sf_re <- matrix(c(65,25,
                      111,-33,
                      82,-77,
                      141, -82,
                      166, -79,
                      -169, -78,
                      -131, -75,
                      -65, -73,
                      -15, -60,
                      -7, -6,
                      35, 14), 
                    ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = 1:2, crs = 4326)

centroid <- sf_re %>% st_union() %>% st_centroid() %>% st_coordinates()

crs_laea <- paste0('+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 ',
                   '+lon_0=',round(centroid[1],2),
                   ' +lat_0=',round(centroid[2],2))

polygon <- sf_re %>%
  st_transform(crs = crs_laea) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON')

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_graticule() %>% st_transform(crs = crs_laea)) + 
  geom_sf(data = polygon, fill = 'dodgerblue')

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = st_graticule()) + 
  geom_sf(data = polygon %>% st_transform(4326), fill = 'dodgerblue')
```

Comment: Haven't found a workaround yet, although it seems that some public shapefiles with global coverages add points near the edge of the map's projection. 

In the meantime, I am performing analysis in local projections.